# Function App consumption plan - Failover/Redundancy

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am a year old in using Azure resources.
I have an HTTP trigger function app and cosmos DB as a backend database. I am using a consumption plan for my function app, which I understand makes the system serverless. And by serverless, I understand I don't have to worry about the infrastructure.

So this serverless system is redundant within the region by default? or do I need to handle failover, by having an extra instance of the function app/cosmos DB in the same region which will serve as a backup instance?

Note - I'm talking about the same region failover, not multi-region redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Availability zone (AZ) support isn't currently available for function apps on  [Consumption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan)  plans.**

***In Consumption Plan, the functions apps SLA is 99.95% of the time.***

It won't failover to a different geo region, no matter the hosting SKU. Use  [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview)  to achieve that level of redundancy.

Needless to say, all resources your function depends on need to exist in the 2nd region as well (SQL instances, Redis, Event Hubs, ...). You are responsible for keeping state consistent across regions (think  [Azure SQL auto-failover groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview#auto-failover-group-capabilities)).

***One notable exception is Cosmos DB, which (if  [configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/distribute-data-globally)) can have automagically-managed replicas in multiple regions. Your function will always use the same connection string.***

**The best you can do (IMHO) is to define the data redundancy as Geo-zone-redundant storage and let Azure handle this for you.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Gonna try this and let's see how it goes :)